# How can I check if a bitwise OR contains a particular value?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, boolean-logic

Say I have the following bitwise operation:

```
1 OR 12 OR 7  => 15
```

Now, is there any way by which I can check if a particular number is part of the value OR'ed together?

For example,

```
7 <Some Operation> 15 = true

4 <Some Operation> 15 = false
```

Comment: There is no way to check, if a particular number is one of the numbers OR'ed together. For example, `10 | 4 => 14` and `10 | 6 => 14`. Is 4 one of the numbers OR'ed together? However, 9 definetely is not OR'ed together in 14. Number _x_ definetely is not OR'ed together in _z_, if _x&z != x_.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check, if a particular value `Val` was *potentially* part of an `Or` operation leading to the result `Res` you have, by testing

```
(Val And Res) = Val
```

If true, this could have been the case.

For your `7 <some operation> 15` example you will find:

```
(0111b And 1111b) = 0111b (True)
```

and for your `4 <some operation> 15` example:

```
(0100b And 1111b) = 0100b (True as well!)
```

The second example does tell you, that 4 could have been involved, but not, that it was involdve with certainty.